# Python function for changing the subject line of an Outlook mail item

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com, mailitem

Is there a Python function for changing the subject line of an Outlook mail item?

I have seen solutions for this using VBA. Was looking for a function/ method in python.

Thanks

**Update**:
Here's what i am trying :

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
folder = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = folder.Items

# Change the current subject line to 'Testing subject change'
messages.GetFirst().Subject = 'Testing subject change'
```

However, the subject line doesn't change. Is there any specific function i should be using?

Comment: I haven't found any. Hence posting the question. If you know of any existing answers, could you please paste the link? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short piece of code will replace all Subject lines of all emails in the specified folder, in this case "Drafts" (provided your Office is in English)

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
acc = outlook.Folders("myaddress@provider.com")
eMailFolder = acc.folders("Drafts") #This is the localized name of your folder, as it appears in Outlook's GUI

def replaceSubjectLine(email:object):
        print(email.Subject)
        email.Subject = "This is the new subject line"
        email.Save
        print(email.Subject)

for message in eMailFolder.Items:
    replaceSubjectLine(message)
```

In Short: You read in the MailItem Object into Python, then changed one of its Properties (Subject), but you never `.Save` the changed MailItem to Outlook.

Comment: Thank you very much